# Operator == cannot be applied to java.lang.String char

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I do not get any errors in NetBeans Java Application, but I do get the mentioned error when applying the code into a Android Java Project. I tried `if (alpha[i].equals(c)) {` but then I would get no results like I do in NetBeans, which is converting a String to Morse e.g. `SOS` to `... --- ...`

NetBeans Java Application (works, when I type SOS I get ... --- ...):

```
private static String toMorse(String text) {
    char[] characters = text.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    StringBuilder morseString = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : characters) {
        for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
            if (alpha[i] == c) {
                morseString.append(morse[i] + " ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return morseString.toString();
}
```

Android Java Project (doesn't work, when I type in a String, I get nothing):

```
public String toMorse(String text) {
    char[] characters = text.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    StringBuilder morseString = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : characters) {
        for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
            if (alpha[i] == c) { // error is on this line
                morseString.append(morse[i] + " ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return morseString.toString();
}
```

Strange part is that this part of the code works in both NetBeans and Android Studio (when I type in ... --- ... I get SOS):

```
public String toEnglish(String text) {
    String[] strings = text.split(" ");
    StringBuilder translated = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : strings) {
        for (int i = 0; i < morse.length; i++) {
            if (morse[i].equals(s)) {
                translated.append(alpha[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return translated.toString();
}
```

alpha and morse arrays:

```
private String[] alpha = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
    "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
    "W", "X", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
"9", "0", " "};

private String[] morse = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.",
    "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.",
    "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-",
    "-.--", "--..", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....",
"-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", "-----", "|"};
```

Comment: Added it to my question

Comment: comparing String to char at (alpha[i] == c) ? try (alpha[i].charAt(0) == c) instead. you shouldn't compare a String to a primitive char .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `alpha` is an array of `String` while `c` is a character. 
you are comparing `(char == string)` which obviously doesn't work like expected.

Comment: Well... it might be late, it might be I'm blind. Array is String not char in Android Studio, in NetBeans it's char. Ok, this question was absolutely unnecessary to post. I looked and looked, and didn't find it ...

Comment: I really doubt that the IDE makes any difference. Probably you have copy & paste something wrong which leads to the assumption that it works on netbeans

Comment: Yes indeed, copy pasted only the loop and not the arrays

Comment: Btw. there is a more performanter way. Either use a `Map<Char, String>`  or use guava's `BiMap` if you want to have the possibilitiy to query bidirectional http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html or if you are only working with ASCII characters you could convert the character to the ascii number `int asciiChar = (int) myChar;` then you can calculate the alphabet-array index by subtracting `(int) 'a'` or `(int) 'A' ` from `asciiChar` ... You may google for the ascii table then it should become more clear ...

Answer (score 2):

`alpha` is an array of `String` (not `char`), one possible fix

```
private char[] alpha = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
    'W', 'X', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
    '9', '0', ' '};
```

another is

```
if (alpha[i].charAt(0) == c) { // <-- a String is not a char.
```

Comment: You mean`alpha[i].charAt(0)`?

Answer (score 1):

`alpha[c]` returns a String (e.g. `alpha[1]` is String "B").
Since `alpha` only contains single-character strings, it can be converted to a character array:

```
private char[] alpha = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
    'W', 'X', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
'9', '0', ' '};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  char[] alpha1 = new char[26] {
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D',
  'E',
  'F',
  'G',
  'H',
  'I',
  'J',
  'K',
  'L',
  'M',
  'N',
  'O',
  'P',
  'Q',
  'R',
  'S',
  'T',
  'U',
  'V',
  'W',
  'X',
  'Y',
  'Z'
};
char[] cipher = new char[26] {
  'Z',
  'Y',
  'X',
  'W',
  'V',
  'U',
  'T',
  'S',
  'R',
  'Q',
  'P',
  'O',
  'N',
  'M',
  'L',
  'K',
  'J',
  'I',
  'H',
  'G',
  'F',
  'E',
  'D',
  'C',
  'B',
  'A'
};
string plain = textBox1.Text;
char[] N = textBox1.Text.ToArray();
textBox3.Text = "";
int X = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < alpha1.Length; i++) {
  if (N[0] == alpha1[0])
    textBox3.Text += cipher[X];
  X++;
}
//..............DISPLAY
textBox3.Text = "";
int b = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < cipher.Length; i++) {
  textBox3.Text += cipher[b];

}
b++;
```

Comment: what is problem